# Android RatingBar onRatingChanged doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, ratingbar, listeners

In my Android app I've got a Fragment showing a RatingBar, which has a onRatingChanged listener that is not responding to ratingbar changes.

So here's my code:

**rating_fragment.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rating_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_fragment_ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stepSize="1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/rating_fragment_whatswrong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/rating_fragment_whatswrong"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RatingFragment.java**

```
public class RatingFragment extends DialogFragment implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{

private static final String TAG = RatingFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private View rootView;
private EditText mWhatsWrong;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a new AlertDialog.Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_fragment,null);

    // Inflate the layout
    builder.setView(R.layout.rating_fragment);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.rating_fragment_title));

    initialize();
    return builder.create();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_fragment,container,false);
    return rootView;
}



private void initialize(){
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_fragment_ratingbar);
    mWhatsWrong = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_fragment_whatswrong);

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onRatingChanged (RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(rating < 4.0f){
        mWhatsWrong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mWhatsWrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:** The onRatingChanged() method gets invoked.

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR:**  Even if I change the stars in the widget, nothing happens.

Comment: You can add `initialize()` method to `onCreateView()` method and have a try.

Comment: @KeLiuyue I've tried it, but it doesn't changed the situation :(

Comment: Hi Gio G.,I use your code and try.It worked.You can check it.Just add `initialize()` method in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Hi KeLiuyue, I've applied the changes but nothing happens as I told you before. I also saw this in the Logcat `W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed`. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Hi Gio G.,I edited again.You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a new AlertDialog.Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_fragment, null);

    // Inflate the layout
    builder.setView(R.layout.rating_fragment);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.rating_fragment_title));
    // edited here
    // initialize();
    return builder.create();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_fragment, container, false);
    // edited here,add initialize() method
    initialize();
    return rootView;
}


private void initialize() {
    // edited here,add log info
    Log.e("RatingBar", "initialize start");
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_fragment_ratingbar);
    mWhatsWrong = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_fragment_whatswrong);

    // edited here
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean b) {

            if (rating < 4.0f) {
                mWhatsWrong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mWhatsWrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            Log.e("RatingBar", rating + "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed, in the Logcat `Log.e("RatingBar", "initialize start");`  appears, but the log `Log.e("RatingBar", rating + "");` in onRatingChanged() doesn't appear. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You can try again.

Comment: I resolved, apperently I made a mistake in the `onCreateDialog` method when i wrote `builder.setView(R.layout.rating_fragment);` instead of passing the rootView alredy inflated in this way: `builder.setView(rootView);`

Comment: Thanks you anyway @KeLiuyue