# RatingBar onRatingChanged is not being called

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

For some reason, my `OnRatingBarChangeListener` will not work. The `onRatingChanged` is not being called and I have no clue why. Searching on StackOverflow yielded no answers. I am using Log.d to see if the listener is working, but when I change the number of stars, nothing is printed in logcat. I also originally had the initialize function as onCreate but changed it for an answer to this question: [Android RatingBar onRatingChanged doesn't get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690580/android-ratingbar-onratingchanged-doesnt-get-called)

Here is the Java code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class WarriorFragment extends Fragment implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{
    int starsNum;
    SharedPreferences stars;
    RatingBar rb;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_warrior, container, false);
        initialize();
        return view;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        stars = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        rb = (RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.strengthStarWarrior);
        if(rb != null) {
            Log.d("debug", "not null");
            rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
            starsNum = stars.getInt("WarriorStrength", -1);
            if (starsNum == -1) {
                rb.setNumStars(0);
                Log.d("debug", "no save");
            } else {
                rb.setNumStars(starsNum);
                Log.d("debug", "save");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
        Log.d("debug", "changed");
        /*SharedPreferences.Editor edit = stars.edit();
        edit.putInt("WarriorStrength", rb.getNumStars());
        edit.apply();*/
    }
}
```

And the xml for this fragment, where the RatingBar is located:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/strengthStarWarrior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.744"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/intellectStarWarrior"
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.74"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.342" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/wisdomStarWarrior"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.757"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.598" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/dexterityStarWarrior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.744"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.856" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trait"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Strength"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.094"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.134" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trait2"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Intellect"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trait3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Wisdom"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trait4"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Dexterity"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.095"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.826" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classTitle"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Warrior"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.651"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Init your `rb` to your `view` not to the context

Comment: I am new to Android Studio, so bear with me. What do you mean by that? What exactly do I have to do?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. Thanks! If anyone else has this problem, I just changed `rb = (RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.strengthStarWarrior);` to `rb = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.strengthStarWarrior);` To get view I just set a parameter for initialize and passed it from onCreateView.